# Two cones intersecting in an ellipse (implicit form)

Tags: geometry

I have two cones with different opening angles, both open two the top and both with their tip on two different points on the xy-plane.[image: the two cones]

Two cones with those properties always intersect in a curve which, projected vertically onto the xy-plane, is a circle.

This property (the projection being a circle) is what I'm trying to prove.

My approach so far is, to get the implicit form for the intersection curve, projecting this onto the xy-plane and then showing that the result is circular.

The two cones are given in implicit form. Let the cones be called $C_1$ and $C_2$, the points of their tips $a_1, a_2$ and the parameter of their opening angle $b_1, b_2$. The implicit formula describing a cone is then:

$C_n: \{p \in \mathbb{R^3}: (x - a_{nx})^2 + (y - a_{ny})^2 - (b_1 \cdot z)^2 = 0, z > 0\}$

I'm now looking for the implicit formula of the curve describing their intersection to then project this curve back onto the xy-plane. How do I get there? I tried subtracting the formulas of the two cones:

$$(x-a_{1x})^2 + (y-a_{1y})^2 - (b_1z)^2) - [(x-a_{2x})^2 + (y - a_{2y})^2 - (b_2z)^2] = 0$$
$$\implies (2a_{1x}-2a_{2x})x + (2a_{2y}-2a_{1y})y + (b_2^2-b_1^2)z^2 + (a_{1x}^1 - a_{2x}^2 + a_{1y}^2 - a_{2y}^2) = 0$$

This result describes an extruded parabola - assumingly the bended plane that the curve is lying on.

(Please excuse my english, it's not my mother tongue)

Comment: What is your question, exactly? You will never get the equation of an ellipse, because an ellipse lies in a plane.

Comment: I'm trying to prove, that the vertical projection of the intersection curve onto the xy-plane is always a circle.

Comment: That is not at all clear from your question!

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question to clarify the goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eliminating $z$ from

$$
\cases{
(x-x_1)^2+(y-y_1)^2-(b_1 z)^2=0\\
(x-x_2)^2+(y-y_2)^2-(b_2 z)^2=0
}
$$

we have

$$
b_2^2((x-x_1)^2+(y-y_1)^2)-b_1^2((x-x_2)^2+(y-y_2)^2)=0
$$

and after grouping

$$
(b_2^2-b_1^2)x^2+(b_2^2-b_1^2)y^2-2(b_2^2x_1-b_1^2x_2)x-2(b_2^2y_1-b_1^2y_2)y=b_1^2(x_2^2+y_2^2)-b_2^2(x_1^2+y_1^2)
$$

which is a circle equation as far as $\frac{b_1^2(x_2^2+y_2^2)-b_2^2(x_1^2+y_1^2)}{(b_2^2-b_1^2)} > 0$

Comment: It's always a circle, unless $b_1^2=b_2^2$.

Answer (score 2):

Eliminate $z$ from the equations of the cones.

$$x^2+y^2=p^2z^2,\\(x-a)^2+y^2=q^2z^2.$$

You immediately get

$$q^2x^2+q^2y^2=p^2(x-a)^2+p^2y^2$$ or $$(p^2-q^2)x^2+(p^2-q^2)y^2+2ap^2x-a^2p^2=0$$ which is the equation of a circle.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to eliminate $z$ from your two equations. So before you subtract them, multiply the first by $b_2^2$ and the second by $b_1^2$. Then $z$ disappears, and you get the equation of a circle in the $(x,y)$-plane.